# How to avoid WebException for 403 Forbidden response?

Tags: c#, performance, exception, httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

I have an application which sometimes must do some requests to the server to see that those requests are properly blocked. In other words, the **expected** server answer is 403 Forbidden.

With a piece of code like this:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(protectedPage);
httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
WebResponse response = HttpRequest.GetResponse();
```

a `WebException` is thrown on the last line.

When profiling code, this exception in a try/catch block has a performance impact which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to check for server response, expecting a 403, without having to catch an exception (but avoiding using sockets directly)?

Comment: I don't see how catching that exception would affect performance at all. I mean it takes nothing compared to how long it takes to receive a webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a [vexing exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) in the framework, and there's no way to avoid it (while still using the `HttpWebRequest` class). But, as High pointed out, this exception handling will take nanoseconds, while the web request itself will take milliseconds (at best), so don't worry about it.

The `WebException` object has a `Response` property that contains the response; when you handle the exception, it's important to dispose that `WebResponse` object (to avoid leaking connections).

Comment: @Tergiver, I think this is a situation where one use case's vexing exception is another use case's exogenous exception.  `File.Open` throws if you don't have permission to read the file, `HttpWebRequest` is doing the analogous thing here.

Answer (score 2):

What's taking time in the profiling is probably not the exception catching part but the actual response from the web site.

The WebException.Status property will give you the status code for the HTTP response and you can do further processing based on that.

Comment: WebException.Status just indicates a Protocol Error.  It doesn't give the status code.

Comment: You have to cast the exception.Response to `HttpWebResponse` and check the `response.StatusCode` property.

Comment: Thanks, ((HttpWebResponse)(we.Response)).StatusCode gives the value as you said.